# What is the best solution to transfer a database backup from a sql server to a buildserver( that its used for jenkins) automated

Tags: sql, sql-server, jenkins, ftps

My solution was to use

- sqlcmd to backup the database
- ftps to transfer the database
- sqlcmd to restore the backup on the building server.
- all of that will be executed by the jenkins, which is on the build server.

My question is that I can't find a secure ftp server-client that support command line. I tried with filezilla but it doesn't support cmd line.

- Do you know a good ftps server and client that support cmd line?
- Or do you have an other solution for my problem?

Why I am asking for help: 
- because i am stuck in the ftps transfer, using CLI.

Comment: I solved the ftps problem using winscp.exe for client, which has a good CLI http://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline
For server i used a IIS ftp server.

Answer (score 3):

FileZilla does support CLI. You can find more on that [here](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_%28Client%29).

You can also try [SSLFTP](http://netwinsite.com/surgeftp/sslftp.htm).

Comment: I tried with filezilla but it doesn't support get or post command. I was able just to connect to server and that was all. When I was trying to get a file it wasn't supported. And if you read the filezilla documentation will see that it doesn't have a command for get/post. 
I think that SSLFTP will solve my problem :) Thanks!
After I will tried I will come with feedback